# Python: Test if an argument is an integer

Tags: python, validation, parameters

I want to write a python script that takes 3 parameters. The first parameter is a string, the second is an integer, and the third is also an integer.

I want to put conditional checks at the start to ensure that the proper number of arguments are provided, and they are the right type before proceeding.

I know we can use sys.argv to get the argument list, but I don't know how to test that a parameter is an integer before assigning it to my local variable for use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're running Python 2.7, try importing [argparse](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/). Python 3.2 will also use it, and it is the new preferred way to parse arguments.

This sample code from the Python [documentation page](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) takes in a list of ints and finds either the max or the sum of the numbers passed.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Answer (score 20):

[`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) can be used to test if a string is comprised solely of numbers.

Answer (score 11):

More generally, you can use `isinstance` to see if something is an instance of a class.

Obviously, in the case of script arguments, everything is a string, but if you are receiving arguments to a function/method and want to check them, you can use:

```
def foo(bar):
    if not isinstance(bar, int):
        bar = int(bar)
    # continue processing...
```

You can also pass a tuple of classes to isinstance:

```
isinstance(bar, (int, float, decimal.Decimal))
```

Comment: not applicable to this case, all cmd-line arguments are received as strings. but i did not know that one can pass tupples to isinstance, so thanks - i learnt.

Answer (score 6):

Python way is to try and fail if the input does not support operation like

```
try:
   sys.argv = sys.argv[:1]+map(int,sys.argv[1:])
except:
   print 'Incorrect integers', sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: I used this construct (`except TypeError`) but it didn't catch as a `TypeError` for value `1x`.  I got `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1x'`.  So I will respectfully edit the answer to make the `except` generic.

Comment: Except for the `print` parentheses that should be included for python 3.4+, can the above `try` block be used as is for python 3.4+ ???  ----  I get an error, that says I cannot concatenate `map` to list. As a result the test always jump to the exception clause. Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

You can use type to determine the type of any object in Python. This works in Python 2.6, I don't personally know if it's present in other versions.

```
obvious_string = "This is a string."
if type(obvious_string) != int:
    print "Bro, that is so _not_ an integer."
else:
    print "Thanks for the integer, brotato chip."
```

Comment: The problem with this is that all arguments passed through sys.argv are by definition strings -- what the poster needs to know is 'can I convert this argument to an int or not?' If not using argparse, the best way is (as noted elsewhere) to try the conversion inside a try/except block.

Answer (score 3):

I am new to Python so I am posting this not only to help but also be helped: get comments on why my approach is/isn't the the best one, that is.

So, with the disclaimer that I am not an experienced python dev, here is what I would do:

```
inp = sys.argv[x]
try:
    input = int(inp)
except ValueError:
    print("Input is not an integer")
```

What the above does is that it puts sys.argv[x] to inp and then tries to put the integer form of inp to input. If there is not an integer form of inp then inp is not a number so a ValueError exception is raised.

I take it that's your main problem and you know how to check if you have all three parameters in the correct form. If not, just let us know and I am sure you will get more answers. :)

*Just realized [Tony Veijalainen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392132/tony-veijalainen) posted a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228757/python-test-if-an-argument-is-an-integer/4228785#4228785)*

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> int('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

Give it to `int`. If it doesn't raise a `ValueError` then the string was an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the argument and try... except the ValueError.

If you are using sys.argv, also investigate argparse.